# How to save the text from richtextbox after changing the formats at runtime in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote some text in richtextbox at runtime and I changed the format of text.Suppose to Bold,Italic,changing the font verdana to Arial,changing the fontsize from 10 to 14 etc.
when i clicked on save text is saving in .txt format and when I opened it after saving from richtextbox or normally,it is showing the default format which is in textfile(notepad) but not into the format which I changed at runtime.
this is the code I used for saving the text in richtextbox.

```
        if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
              richtextbox1.SaveFile(savefiledialog.FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: take a look at the obvious - look at the last parameter you gave SaveFile...

Comment: Last parameter I used is plaintext,instead of plaintext which one I should use to save the format settings which I changed at runtime

Answer (score 1):

USE

```
RTP.SaveFile("D:\RtfFile.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

When you are using PlainText that means application will not save text with formats. You assign the extension .rtf file must be saved in RichTextFormat.

**UPDATE:**

```
string fileName = string.Empty;

private void SaveFile()
{
    if (fileName ==string.Empty)
    {
        if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            fileName = savefiledialog.FileName;
    }
    if (fileName != string.Empty)
    {
        try
        {
            richtextbox1.SaveFile(FileName,RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I did some changes and clicks on save again savefiledialog is opening,there is any chance to save automatically without opening the dialog again like microsoft word.

Comment: when I am opening the file it is showing some junk text with the original text like this {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs40 ggggggggggggggggggggggggg \f1     \f2\fs28  hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh\f1\fs20\par
}    here ggggg and hhhh is the text remaing is junk text

Comment: This is not junk text. it is a format of rich text just like html tags. if you want to save any text with bold/italic/underline then it requires the starting tag and closing tag of formatted text. fs40, fs28 is class same as css class which is declared at the top of the documents. it will contains all text properties like font name, font size, color etc. so, if you want to save text with formatting then you must have to save text along with all tags.

Comment: those are html tags I also understood but those tags should not be shown in richtextbox when it is opened

Comment: Use [`RichTextBox.LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7.aspx) method to load file (rtf or normal text).